How to use External Services within Illuminated Cloud
I was able to register a REST API as an External Service via the Open API spec in my sandbox.  When I refresh the metadata in Illumnated Cloud, my Apex code doesn't resolve the ExternalService namespace / class name and cannot find the registered classes / methods.
Is there a special type of object that these fall under that I need to include, or is this just not supported in IC?

N.B. IC2 questions will get ably and quickly answered by the product owner through the IC2 forum @ScottWells

@cropredy - thank you, this forum doesn't come up in google searches for support/documentation.

I found a fix to the issue - In the module configuration, "External Services" needs to be checked in the list of local files.  After that, reindexing the project did the trick.
